# Употребление аббревиатур в устной речи

Tags: аббревиатура

Можно ли употреблять такую аббревиатуру как "ФИО" в устной речи? А именно в диалоге с клиентом по телефону. Пример: "Необходимо будет указать ФИО, адрес, номер телефона..." Допустимо ли использовать эту аббревиатуру либо она подходит лишь для использования в разговорной речи? Если нет, то желательно объяснить почему. На моей работе (в КЦ) руководство запрещает употреблять эту аббревиатуру в разговоре с клиентом, объясняя тем, что это "БЫТОВОЕ ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ". Лично я считаю, что использование "ФИО" вполне допустимо, как и других аббревиатур.

Comment: Если Вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как правильный.

Answer (score 3):

Это не бытовое выражение, а канцеляризм.
 Причем исключительно письменный, так что Ваш начальник, хоть и не прав с
 обоснованием, прав по сути.

Литературной нормой будет "укажите *фамилию, имя и отчество*", хотя в устной речи
вполне допустим и более разговорный вариант "*фамилию-имя-отчество*".

ФИО, точнее Ф. И. О., - это условное сокращение, а не аббревиатура. Также 
аббревиатурой не будут инициалы или выражения вроде *т. е., и т. д., до н.
 э.* и др. При чтении такие сокращения, в отличие от аббревиатур, читаются
 полностью: *то есть, и так далее, до нашей эры*. Если Вы будете 
произносит Ф. И. О. как аббревиатуру, то слушатель Вас может не понять.

Comment: Спасибо Вам

Answer (score 0):

ФИО – это не аббревиатура.

**Обновление**

Это канцелярское сокращение для наименования графы (строки, столбца) в таблице. А то очень длинно получается, просто не влезет. Ни в устной, ни в письменной речи не употребляется. Ну, может быть, кроме канцелярского жаргона, и то вряд ли.